# Hibernate/Spring list with generics?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, generics, jpa

I'm having some tables which contains same structure of data but with different type.
So I was thinking I can do it with generics but I have some problems.

This is my code:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class CheckList {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  long id;

  List<Date> dates;
  List<TableNamedRow<Boolean>> rows; // <---- Here I'm using generics
}
```

And here is how I would like to use it. But I'm receiving error "cannot select from the type of variable"

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class TableNamedRow<T> {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  long id;

  String name;

  @ElementCollection(targetClass = T.class) // <--- here is error
  List<T> cell;
}
```

Is there way to do it or some workaround to don't do all of the staff for each table?

Comment: I think `T` should be upper bounded by `extends`, and the upper bound is to be used as `targetClass`.

Comment: If you put a (generic) type in the List there is no need to put "targetClass", any JPA provider worth its salt can get hold of the List element "type" via generics.